# Javascript Regex for showing variable followed by a specific word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using Datatable's search plugin to display only those rows that have the value as the variable 'member' in column index 0.

```
document.getElementById(orderid).textContent = "Collapse";
table.columns(0).search("^"+member+"/Collapse*/",true).draw();
```

What I want is only those rows to be dislayed which have the 'member' variable in column 0 or 'member' variable followed by Collapse anywhere in the column.

Eg. For Column0

```
10
100
1000
10     Collapse
20
```

I want the search to return only 10 and 10 Collapse when I search the regex with '10' as member. How do I write the regex for this search?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `g` at the and of the serach string for a global search (return all results, not only one)

```
"^"+member+"/Collapse*/g"
```

Comment: This is returning 0 records.

Comment: @randomnessrandomly, what does your current search (in the question) return?

Answer (score 0):

Building on JNF's answer: Try to add the global search `g` and the multiline `m` modifier.
Furthermore you also need to match the *whitespace* between the member identifier and the word "Collapse".

Something like this should do the trick:

```
"/^"+member+"(\s+Collapse)?$/gm"
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/eM0cV5/1

Third, you should disable *smart search*. Extract from [Datatables - search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search%28%29)

> Note that to perform a smart search, DataTables uses regular expressions, so if enable regular expressions using the second parameter to this method, you will likely want to disable smart searching as the two regular expressions might otherwise conflict and cause unexpected results.

Comment: Hey, this should work but I am getting zero rows returned. Maybe Datatables follows a different flavour of RegExp?

Comment: yes. that's possible. apparently datatables doesn't support modifiers at the end of the regex. did you try it without? can you paste your code into http://jsfiddle.net/? so that I can improve my answer.